# Simulate click external domain

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I try simulate click to share on G+ from my web site :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste share G+</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert('hiii');document.getElementById('share_g').click();">
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com" id="share_g" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');document.querySelector('span.RveJvd snByac').click(); return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>

    </body>
</html>
```

At this point work good, but i need click to `POST`, is possible simulate this click with `javascript or pahntomjs` ?

Comment: It seems to automatically run when I use your code on this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5s91ztvh/. Can you please clarify what do you mean by click to POST?

Comment: tks for atention, yeah run automatic up to a point, and on this point i need click `POST` button to finish operation... I need simulate this click... Some tip?

Comment: Sorry - see what you mean now. I'm not sure I know a way to do this - my first thought though is to embed this into an iframe rather than an href, and see whether you can then use the parent page to click on it using javascript. I don't think I can do this with jsfiddle because it would involve embedding an iframe from another page (the error I got was "Refused to display 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com,' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.")

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the proper documentation [Here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/), There is no need to post from javascript

Comment: tks for atention, u can show me the point to i post without any click on this documentation?

Comment: You won't be able to automatically do this unless your running it under some sort of automation script such as nodejs.
If this is the case, dont do this in browser, use the proper rest API, Documentation can be found here; https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/